# Sorting and filtering Multi Dimensional array from API in angular

Tags: angular, angular12

Here is my API data

```
{
id: 1, name: "pro package", 
subscriptionList: [ {id: 1, amount: 999}, {id: 2, amount: 2999}, {id: 3, amount: 1999} ]
},
{
id: 2, name: "basic package", 
subscriptionList: [ {id: 1, amount: 299} ]
}
```

Desired Result is

```
Basic Package - 299
Pro Package - Starting from 999 - 2999
```

This is how im sorting right now

```
this._services.subscriptionapi().subscribe((result) => {
this.packages = result.sort(
  (a, b) =>
   b.subscriptionList[0].amount -
   a.subscriptionList[0].amount
);
});
```

How can i sort `amount` inside `subscriptionList` by showing only the Min and Max values (eg: 299 - 2999)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to combine filter and sort functions like this :

```
this._services.subscriptionapi().subscribe((result) => {
this.packages = result.filter(
(a) => 
a.subscriptionList[0].amount > 2999
&& &.subscriptionList[0].amount < 299
)
.sort(
  (a, b) =>
   b.subscriptionList[0].amount -
   a.subscriptionList[0].amount
);
});
```

Hope I understood your question well.

Answer (score 0):

you needn't sort the list. You can simple loop over result and over subscriptionList

```
this.packages=this.result.map((x)=>{
  const obj={min:x.subscriptionList[0].amount,
             max:x.subscriptionList[0].amount,
             name:x.name}
  x.subscriptionList.forEach((y) => {
    obj.min = obj.min > y.amount ? y.amount : obj.min;
    obj.max = obj.max < y.amount ? y.amount : obj.max;
  });
  return obj
})
```